# Angular $http to post formData blob throws ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING error when there's an extra parameter in the url

Tags: angularjs, http, file-upload, form-data, angular-http

I am trying to post a blob as a form data using angular $http. 
The following code works perfectly fine when the request url doesn't have parameter:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('fileName', myBlob);

return $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: <my_url>,
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': undefined
                },
                data: formData
            });
```

The above works perfectly fine with a pure simple url without parameter. 
However, if I try the url with a parameter, it will give ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING error. I tried below:

```
return $http({
                    method: 'PUT',
                    url: <my_url>+"?param1=something",
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': undefined
                    },
                    data: formData
                });
```

I also tried:

```
return $http({
                    method: 'PUT',
                    url: <my_url>,
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    params: {param1: something}
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': undefined
                    },
                    data: formData
                });
```

All give same error. Help much appreciated.

Update: I tried formDate.append("?param1", something). It no longer show the chuncking error. But it doesn't seem to fix the problem. the server won't pick up that parameter. and if i change it back. the same ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING happens. probably due to a file stream not closing? but how would i close the Blob?

Comment: actually, i find this will help, instead of including the parameter in the url,
the below should work: Formdata.append(“?param1”, 100);

Comment: however, the above doesn't fix the problem. the server won't pick up that parameter. and if i change it back. the same ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING happens. probably due to a file stream not closing? but how would i close the Blob?